# fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions

I have been working on this for a week, and have looked at multiple stackoverflow posts, but I have not been able to resolve my issue. I did have this working in my management account, but now im delpoying the same to a development account.

This project is a simple s3 static website, deployed using terraform via a Github Actions pipeline.

I am new to Github Actions so the problem may be located here!

Everything deploys fine, expect that the aws s3 sync command now throws up an error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I believe this is due to permissions on the bucket.

Here is the code to deploy the s3 buckets:

```
# Main bucket for hosting web content

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "static_website_s3_bucket" {
  bucket        = var.domain_name
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "static_website_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.id

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "static_website_s3_bucket_public_access_block" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.static_website_s3_bucket_versioning]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "static_website_s3_bucket_versioning" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration.static_website_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration]
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "static_website_s3_bucket_website_configuration" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "error.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "static_website_s3_bucket_policy" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.static_website_s3_bucket_public_access_block]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.static_website_s3_bucket_policy.json
}

# www bucket for redirecting to web content bucket

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "static_website_s3_bucket_www" {
  bucket        = "www.${var.domain_name}"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "static_website_s3_bucket_website_configuration_www" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket_www.id

  redirect_all_requests_to {
    host_name = var.domain_name
    protocol  = "https"
  }
}
```

There is a Cloudfront Distribution used as well. The bucket policy looks like this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "static_website_s3_bucket_policy" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.static_website_cloudfront_origin_access_control,
    aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket,
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.static_website_s3_bucket_public_access_block
  ]

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalReadOnlyAccessToS3Bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.arn}/*"
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudfront.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceArn"

      values = [
        "arn:aws:cloudfront::${var.account_id}:distribution/${aws_cloudfront_distribution.static_website_cloudfront_distribution.id}"
      ]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowS3ObjectUploads"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.static_website_s3_bucket.arn}/*"
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/eit-${var.environment}-backend-terraform-role"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "static_website_cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  name = "${local.default_parameter_name}/cloudfront/id"
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "static_website_s3_bucket_domain_name" {
  name = "${local.default_parameter_name}/s3/bucket/domain_name"
}
```

As i understand it, there are 2 statements needed here:

1. Cloudfront only to be allowed to read objects from the s3 bucket
2. S3 permissions to allow the role/eit-${var.environment}-backend-terraform-role to upload objects

Everything works fine through the guithub actions until it hits the aws s3 sync command:

```
name: my_name

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  development:
    name: my_name
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      environment: development

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Github Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ vars.AWS_ROLE_MANAGEMENT }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2

      - name: my_name-development
        run: |
          echo "Deploying my_name-resume in to Development account..."
          echo "Remove any existing .terraform directory..."
          rm -Rf .terraform
          echo "Using role: ${{ vars.AWS_ROLE_MANAGEMENT }}"
          echo "Github Repository: ${{ github.repository }}"
          echo "Triggered by : ${{ github.triggering_actor }}"
          aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${{ vars.AWS_ROLE_DEVELOPMENT }} --role-session-name eit-development-backend-terraform-role
          echo "Running terraform init..."
          terraform init -reconfigure \
              -backend-config="backend-config.hcl" \
              -backend-config="env/website/development/backend-config.hcl"
          echo "Running terraform plan..."
          terraform plan \
              -var-file="env/website/development/env.tfvars" -out tfplan.txt
          terraform apply tfplan.txt
          echo "Uploading website assets..."
          aws s3 sync ./website/ s3://my_name.co.uk
          echo "Uploading complete!"
```

Its at this point the pipeline generates this output:

```
Saved the plan to: tfplan.txt

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "tfplan.txt"
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
aws_s3_bucket_policy.static_website_s3_bucket_policy: Modifying... [id=my_name.co.uk]
aws_s3_bucket_policy.static_website_s3_bucket_policy: Modifications complete after 0s [id=my_name.co.uk]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
Uploading website assets...
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

A few notes of my understanding:

1. Block Public Access is set to false for troubleshooting but will turn this back on
2. The Github Action maybe the problem as i'm very new to it, and no doubt needs to be improved
3. S3 bucket is using an OAC so therefore just uses bucket policies

Any help at this point would be very much appreciated. So for the long post!